# Mongo DB ,how to do find with a field contains an integer

Tags: php-mongodb

My collection is like

```
Name : "name" Serial:"100" Name : "name1" Serial:"4200" Name : "name2" Serial:"1200"
```

I need to find documents which contain `Name` that contains value `"name"` or `Serial` that contains `"200"`

Thanks a lot for your guidelines here.

Answer (score 0):

if you have data like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "name" : "nameA", "serial" : 1200 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "name" : "nameB", "serial" : 1234 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "name" : "nameC", "serial" : 4200 }
```

and you want query on field `serial` with regular expression, you can do aggregation:

```
db.coll.aggregate(
    {$project: {name: true, serial: {$toLower: '$serial'}}}, 
    {$match: {serial: /20/}})
)
// { "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "name" : "nameA", "serial" : "1200" }
// { "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "name" : "nameC", "serial" : "4200" }

db.coll.aggregate(
    {$project: {name: true, serial: {$toLower: '$serial'}}}, 
    {$match: {serial: /12/}})
)
// { "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "name" : "nameA", "serial" : "1200" }
// { "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "name" : "nameB", "serial" : "1234" }
```

but this is a hack, I would not use this approach in my work. Maybe there is a way to reorganize your data structure?

And you must know that you can't use any indices with this query, mongo will do full table scan.

Hope I understood your question correctly ;).

Comment: It did not give me a better solution .An example as below          > db.Legacy_details.findOne() --------Collection 
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("573d8f5eeb55cc97e9c07aa5"),
        "Array" : 290103590,
        "Device" : "10000000c987856d",
        "Host" : ""
}
> db.Legacy_details.find({"Array":"290103590"})
> db.Legacy_details.find({"Array":/290103590/})
>

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand you question. If you want to lookup with only part of string then use regex, I see you know about it. If you need disjunction then use `$or` as I did.

Comment: Well, I think I got it, if not please correct me. You have an int field, and you need partial match with it? Ok, I can suggest you to use aggregate function. First you should convert int values into strings, and then match it on your query. To convert ints to string just use modificator `$toLower`.

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Comment: @evilive Nice to see the work around ,could you give me a sample syntax ,as i tried several way and can't get success